# XMLHttpRequest cannot load Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get an http:// javascript file via xhr but I am running into the error mentioned above.

Here's my code:

```
function getXHR() {
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

    if (is_chrome) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://api.widgets.org/widget/1.1.2/widget_api.js?autoCreate=false&log=true", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.textContent = xhr.responseText;
        (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
        s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
    }
}
```

This is only for Chrome because I would like to use the script in https:// but Chrome automatically blocks anything from http://. The server from which I am getting the script does not run https:// and I NEED the script/have multiple scripts I'd rather not all copy down into a data file.

The error I'm running into:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.widgets.org/widget/1.1.2/widget_api.js?autoCreate=false&log=true. Origin https://mysite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just insert the `<script>` tag directly instead of this XHR wrapper and then inserting the content to a `<script>`  tag.

```
function getScript() {
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

    if (is_chrome) {
        // generate script element and set its source
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.src = "http://api.widgets.org/widget/1.1.2/widget_api.js?autoCreate=false&log=true";
        // remove the script element after loading
        s.addEventListener( 'load', function(){ s.parentNode.removeChild(s); } );
        (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
    }
}
```

Besides, I don't know, why you try to remove the script element after loading. This wont affect any of the objects/methods/variables created within that code.

Comment: That's correct. You cannot do this via XHR if the domains are different. Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control

Comment: This option doesn't quite solve the http:// and https:// problem I have. (i.e. [blocked] The page at https://mysite.com ran insecure content from http://api.widgets.org/widget/1.1.2/widget_api.js?autoCreate=false&log=true)

Comment: i'm not entirely sure but i don't think the issue has anything to do with http vs https, it's an issue of cross-domain resources which will be blocked whether the resourse is http or https.

Answer (score 3):

I changed to full path of server file to short path as follows.

```
$.post('http://example.com/pages/loadRandomImages.php',{'type':'loadRandomImages','loadingReq':'True'},function(data){

------------
----------
});
```

Changed it to,

```
$.post('/pages/loadRandomImages.php',{'type':'loadRandomImages','loadingReq':'True'},function(data){

------------
----------
});
```

Then worked fine in chrome.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this answer!! I had an XMLHttpRequest.open() statement that wasn't working because of the cross domain error above and by using a relative path instead, I got Chrome working perfectly. Much much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Browser's block XHR requests made to a server which is different the server of the page making the request, for security purposes related to cross-site scripting.

If it's just a script you want to load, use

```
<script src="..."></script>
```

For general XHR, you can use the jsonp workaround, if the api provides it, or ask the operators of the API to enable CORS (cross-origin resource sharing)

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP